# Vaadin call create a component throught another component

Tags: vaadin, custom-component

I have a Custom component with a `textField` and a `button`, I want to `onClick` (of the Button), get the text from the `textField` and call another Component.

The error I get when I call `mainLayout.addComponent(new A(textField.getValue());` is an
`java.lang.IllegalStateException:` Composition root must be set to non-null value before the `com.example.vaadpro`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception says, you have to call setCompositionRoot for your CustomComponent:

```
public class A extends CustomComponent {

  HorizontalLayout layout = new new HorizontalLayout(); 

  public A() {
    layout.add(new Label("Hello world!"));
    layout.add(new Button("Click me!"));

    setCompositionRoot(layout); // This is needed!
   }
}
```